How can I force my Next.js project to get new data from my getCart function
I am trying to make a very small ecommerce site for a friend's pet business but I am having an issue with the cart page on the next.js project to get the correct information.
this is my function for getCart
export async function getCart(): Promise<ShoppingCart | null> {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  let cart: CartWithProducts | null = null;

  if (session) {
    cart = await prisma.cart.findFirst({
      where: { userId: session.user.id },
      include: { items: { include: { product: true } } },
    });
  } else {
    const localCartId = cookies().get("localCartId")?.value;
    cart = localCartId
      ? await prisma.cart.findUnique({
          where: { id: localCartId },
          include: { items: { include: { product: true } } },
        })
      : null;
  }

  if (!cart) {
    return null;
  }

this is my cart page
import { getCart } from "@/lib/db/cart";
import CartEntry from "./CartEntry";
import { setProductQuantity } from "./actions";
import { formatPrice } from "@/lib/format";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import Link from "next/link";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import CheckoutButton from "@/components/CheckoutButton";

export default async function CartPage() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  const cart = await getCart();

  revalidatePath("/cart");

  const sortedItems = cart?.items.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.product.name.localeCompare(b.product.name);
  });

  let shippingCost = 299;

  if (cart?.subtotal) shippingCost = cart?.size > 1 ? 0 : 299;

  return (
    <div className="mt-4 sm:mt-0">
      <div>
        <h1 className="mb-2 text-center text-3xl font-bold">Shopping Cart</h1>
        {sortedItems?.length && cart?.subtotal != undefined ? (
          <h2
            style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}
            className="flex flex-col flex-wrap items-center justify-between gap-3 sm:flex-row md:pl-20 md:pr-20 lg:pl-52 lg:pr-52"
          >
            Selected Items
          </h2>
        ) : null}
        {sortedItems?.map((cartItem) => (
          <CartEntry
            cartItem={cartItem}
            key={cartItem.id}
            setProductQuantity={setProductQuantity}
          />
        ))}
        <h4 className="my-10 text-center text-3xl font-bold">
          {!sortedItems?.length && (
            <>
              <p>Your Cart is empty.</p>
              <Link
                href="/"
                className="btn btn-primary mt-16 rounded-full sm:w-[200px]"
              >
                Go To Home Page <HomeIcon />
              </Link>
            </>
          )}
        </h4>
        {sortedItems?.length && cart?.subtotal != undefined ? (
          <>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
              <p className="mb-1">Subtotal: {formatPrice(cart?.subtotal)}</p>
              <div>
                Shipping:{" "}
                {shippingCost === 0 ? (
                  <h2 className="inline font-bold text-green-700">{"Free"}</h2>
                ) : (
                  formatPrice(shippingCost)
                )}
              </div>

              <p className="mt-3 font-bold">
                Total: {formatPrice(cart?.subtotal + shippingCost)}
              </p>
              <p className="my-2 text-xs">* Tax Calculated At Checkout</p>
              <div className="mr-2">
                <CheckoutButton />
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


and this is the link to take the person to the cart in the navbar
      <Link href="/cart" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
           View Cart
      </Link>

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the revalidate path because I console.out what is returned from the cart, which is old information. But Next.js is still new to me, so maybe I am using it wrong. That said, I also tried putting
export const revalidate = 0;

to not cache any information at the top of the cart page, but that doesn't seem to help either. The only thing that does seem to work is to manually refresh the page or replace my Link to the cart page with
          <button
              className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
              onClick={() => {
                window.location.href = "/cart"; 
              }}
            >
              View Cart
        </button>

This also forces a refresh, but I would prefer not to do it this way since it is a hard refresh and it is not as smooth of a transition. So is there a way I can fix this?
Also, what is noticible is that the navbar cart icon correctly has the items and amount in it, but that is a client side component, while the cart is a server side component. Also, when I try to move on the the actual checkout page which I started making with Stripe, it carries over the correct amount.
